# Context issue with AsyncTask

Tags: android

When clicking a button then I want to show an `alertDialog` showing an `animationDrawable` and performing an `asyncTask`. I found that when I set the `context` of the `dialog` to getApplicationContext() then the app crashed , and when I set the context to the parent class `activity` then the `dialog` is dismissed very well when I call the dismiss method in the activity class ; but when I want to dismiss it in the onPostExecute of the AsyncTask then the dialog is not dismissed ! Here are codes :

```
public class SyncActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    private MessageDialogView dlg = null; // an AlertDialog showing a message
    private Patienter dwait = null; // an AlertDialog containing an imageview showing an animation-list
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.synchro);
        ...
        dlg = new MessageDialogView(SyncActivity.this, getLayoutInflater());
        dwait = new Patienter(SyncActivity.this, getLayoutInflater());
        ...
    }
    public void synchroniser(View view) { // called when a button is clicked
        dwait.show();
        new RequestTask().execute("http://192.168.1.8/impots/data/syncro/webVersAndroid/parcelles.txt");
    }
    private class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> { 

        private String err = "";
        private boolean error = false;
        private String[] enregs;

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... s_url) {

            enregs = new String[s_url.length];
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if(networkInfo != null) {
                if (networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                    System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
                    HttpURLConnection con = null;
                    BufferedReader reader = null;
                    for (int u=0; u<s_url.length; u++) {
                        String tmp;
                        String lines = "";
                        try {
                            URL url = new URL(s_url[u]);
                            if (url != null) {
                                con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                                if (con != null && con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                                    InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
                                    reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                                    boolean firstLine = true;
                                    while ((tmp = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                        if (firstLine) {
                                            firstLine = false;
                                            lines += tmp;
                                        }
                                        else
                                            lines += "\r\n" + tmp;
                                    }
                                    enregs[u] = lines;
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            error = true;
                            err = getResources().getString(R.string.errBadUrl);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            error = true;
                            err = getResources().getString(R.string.errAccessError);
                        } finally {
                            if (reader != null) {
                              try {
                                reader.close();
                              } catch (IOException e) {
                              }
                            }
                            if (con != null)
                                con.disconnect();
                        }
                    }
                }   
                else {
                    error = true;
                    err = getResources().getString(R.string.errNotConnected);
                }
            } else {
                error = true;
                err = getResources().getString(R.string.errNoNetwork);
            }
            if (!error)
                populateDB();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            dwait.dismiss();
            if (error) {
                displayError(err);
            }
        }

        private void displayError(String msg) {
            dlg.setTitre(getString(R.string.titreErrMsgBox));
            dlg.setMsg(msg);
            dlg.show();
        }
        ...
      }
    }
  }

Code of the dialog :

    public class Patienter extends AlertDialog {

        private View contenu;
        AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = null;

        public Patienter(Context context, LayoutInflater inflater) {
            super(context);
            contenu = inflater.inflate(R.layout.patienter, null);
            setCancelable(false);
            setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(contenu);
            ImageView img = (ImageView)contenu.findViewById(R.id.imgWait);
            img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wait);
            frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();
            frameAnimation.start();
        }

    }
```

So how to work with the **context** ?

Answer (score 1):

Set your `Context in Constructor of AsyncTask` & pass the context from where AsyncTask called.

`Show your Dialogue in onPreExecute()` of AsyncTask

`Cancel` your Dialogue on `onPostExecute()`.

```
 private class RunInBackground extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private Context contextInsideDialogue;

    public RunInBackground(Context activity) {
        try {

            this.contextInsideDialogue = activity;

            dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity,
                    android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light_Panel);
            dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        try {
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait. . ");
            dialog.show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

    }

@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        try {
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
 }
```

& Invoke it as

```
  RunInBackground task = new RunInBackground (MyActivity.this);
  task.execute();
```

Comment: the dialog does not dismiss !

Comment: Post your updated code.May be the issue is with your extended AlertDialogue.I have seen your last question in SO

Comment: The code of the extended AlertDialog is in my question post.

Comment: The dialog is showing when I click the button , but it does not dismiss after the asynctask execution !

Comment: Is it onPostExecute() triggered

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73755/discussion-between-pheromix-and-don-chakkappan).